# Syncing Heroku's ephemeral storage to Dropbox

Tags: api, heroku, synchronization, dropbox, pocketmine

I'm not sure that this is, well, the ordinary use case for Heroku. I want to run a PocketMine (Minecraft Bedrock Edition server) on Heroku. I've compiled a new PHP build, compiled the Phar, and scripted a compatibility layer between it and Heroku, along with a GUI and eventually some ngrok compatibility.

My problem is that Heroku's storage is ephemeral. Since I don't want to create a big-name storage bucket (S3, GCP, Azure) is it possible that I can use Dropbox or some other free file hosting service.

I'm not sure where to start as considering

1. In all the storage would be up to 100 megabytes, consisting of multiples files.
2. How can you do this efficiently and fast (How do I even do it ?).
3. If possible, how can I zip the data every 10 minutes and continuously sync to dropbox.

If this is possible it would be awesome!

Comment: I _very strongly_ urge you to reconsider this. Write _directly_ to an off-site storage service instead of the local filesystem. Heroku dynos can be restarted at any time, so even "every 10 minutes" might not be sufficient. And pick a real service instead of trying to shoehorn Dropbox into this.

Comment: Writing directly seems like an awesome idea I've never thought of. The reason I'm using dropbox is because I don't necessarily trust giving them a credit card. I've just though of using an FTP server though...